# Need To combine two date parts into a new date field without the results adding

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, data-structures, dataset

I am trying to get two date parts, day and year, to combine into one new data field without adding the results. I do not know what I am doing wrong and any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
sELECT   Convert(varchar,dbo.tblRpt291_AgingSnapshot.ReportDate)as DATEINT, Datepart(DAY,dbo.tblRpt291_AgingSnapshot.ReportDate)+ ''+''+DATEPART(YEAR,dbo.tblRpt291_AgingSnapshot.ReportDate) as Date, dbo.tblRpt291_AgingSnapshot.ReportDate, First.Age AS AvgAge, First.CountOfCalls AS Inventory
FROM         dbo.tblRpt291_AgingSnapshot LEFT OUTER JOIN
                          (SELECT     ReportDate, AVG(CAST(Age AS Numeric)) AS Age, SUM(CAST(CountOfCalls AS Numeric)) AS CountOfCalls
FROM         dbo.tblRpt291_AgingSnapshot AS tblRpt291_AgingSnapshot_1
WHERE     (Client = 'PEMS') AND (WorkableStatus = 'Workable') AND (Worktype IN ('Individual PCP', 'Group PCP'))
GROUP BY ReportDate) AS First ON dbo.tblRpt291_AgingSnapshot.ReportDate = First.ReportDate
WHERE     (MONTH(dbo.tblRpt291_AgingSnapshot.ReportDate) = 12) AND (YEAR(dbo.tblRpt291_AgingSnapshot.ReportDate) in (2013,2014))
GROUP BY dbo.tblRpt291_AgingSnapshot.ReportDate, First.Age, First.CountOfCalls
order by dbo.tblRpt291_AgingSnapshot.ReportDate ​
```

Comment: Are you getting an error? Incorrect results?

Comment: Also, your query would be significantly easier to read if you made use of table aliases.

Comment: yes when I combine it it looks like the year is off for example report date year is 2013 the combined year shows 2014

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `CAST()` as string the two parts before concatenating, so they are not added together, because `DATEPART()` is returning an integer:

```
, CAST(Datepart(DAY,dbo.tblRpt291_AgingSnapshot.ReportDate) AS VARCHAR(5))+CAST(DATEPART(YEAR,dbo.tblRpt291_AgingSnapshot.ReportDate) AS VARCHAR(5)) as Date
```

Additionally, table aliases will help with readability, and I suggest avoiding using keywords as aliases:

```
SELECT   Convert(varchar,a.ReportDate)as DATEINT
       , CAST(Datepart(DAY,a.ReportDate) AS VARCHAR(5))+CAST(DATEPART(YEAR,a.ReportDate) AS VARCHAR(5)) as Dt
       , a.ReportDate
       , b.Age AS AvgAge
       , b.CountOfCalls AS Inventory
FROM         dbo.tblRpt291_AgingSnapshot a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN     (SELECT     ReportDate, AVG(CAST(Age AS Numeric)) AS Age, SUM(CAST(CountOfCalls AS Numeric)) AS CountOfCalls
                     FROM         dbo.tblRpt291_AgingSnapshot AS tblRpt291_AgingSnapshot_1
                     WHERE     (Client = 'PEMS') AND (WorkableStatus = 'Workable') AND (Worktype IN ('Individual PCP', 'Group PCP'))
                     GROUP BY ReportDate) AS b
    ON a.ReportDate = b.ReportDate
WHERE     (MONTH(a.ReportDate) = 12) AND (YEAR(a.ReportDate) in (2013,2014))
GROUP BY a.ReportDate, b.Age, b.CountOfCalls
order by a.ReportDate ​
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast your datepart's - SQL is treating them as integers, you want them to behave like text.

As an example:

```
select cast(Datepart(DAY,getdate()) AS varchar(2)) + 

cast(DATEPART(YEAR,getdate()) AS varchar(4)) as Date
```

Replace the getdate() with your column name.